# Flex not parsing variable names properly

Tags: flex-lexer

I'm new to using Flex.  Here's my lex file:

```
%{
    #include <stdio.h>
%}

%%

\w[\w\d]+    printf("WORD\n");
.            printf("OTHER\n");

%%

int main() {
    yylex();
    return 0;
}
```

I then compile this with

```
flex lexfile.l && gcc lex.yy.c -ll
```

However, after running

```
echo "hello" | ./a.out
```

I get

```
UNKNOWN
UNKNOWN
UNKNOWN
UNKNOWN
UNKNOWN
```

Why wouldn't I get

```
WORD
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah.  Looks like Flex's version of regex doesn't understand \w and \d.  Replaced with

```
[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]+
```

and it worked fine.

Comment: A more idiomatic pattern would be `[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]*` (Use `+` instead of `*` only if you want to prohibit single-character variable names.)